# InvalidInput: Invalid request on AWS Route 53

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I am trying to set resource records in AWS route 53 via the SDK and I am getting an Invalid Request error(InvalidInput). Can you double check my params to make sure that I have them set correctly?

```
function testw () {
var params = {
ChangeBatch: { 
Changes: [ 
  {
    Action: 'CREATE',
    ResourceRecordSet: {
      Name: 'example.com', 
      Type: 'A', 
      AliasTarget: {
        DNSName: 's3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
        EvaluateTargetHealth: false,
        HostedZoneId: 'Z1YU6G6WEXAMP'
      },
     }
    },
  ],
    Comment: 'This is a test and it should be working.'
   },
 HostedZoneId: 'Z1YU6G6WEXAMP'
};
route53.changeResourceRecordSets(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
 });
}
```

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try removing the TTL?  When you use aliases, you do not specify the TTL as Route 53 will use the target's TTL.  Also, per the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html), your alias target zone id should be Z3AQBSTGFYJSTF.

Comment: This worked but presented a different problem.  Now I am getting an InvalidChangeBatch error saying alias target name does not lie within the target zone.  Any ideas?  Thanks for your help so far!!!